# Node.js and pooled database connections

Tags: node.js

Do node.js applications benefit from database connection pooling or not?

I assume in some cases they would benefit from a pool of connections and in some cases they wouldn't benefit from more than 1 connection. Can someone please describe a few simple scenarios that support both standpoints?

Comment: This depends on how you construct your application.  There is no yes/no answer to this question.  If you want to use connection pooling, use connection pooling.  If not, don't.  It's up to you.  Node.js itself has no database bindings.  For that, you need to install packages, and there are many to choose from.

Comment: thanks, what do you mean by database bindings? you may mean node.js is not bound to a particular DB vendor?

Comment: is there a particular node.js module that can manage synchronized access to a mongodb collection pool? any recommendations?

Comment: no. only asynchronously access. but you can use https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall for executing queries in series and high level http://mongoosejs.com/ orm to speed up development and improve code

Comment: @AlexMills It's my understanding that MongoDB is not truly ever synchronized across multiple servers, by its nature.

Comment: @AlexMills Node.js itself has no provisions for connecting to a database.  There are modules available for connecting to databases.  The concept of a database isn't even built into Node.js.  It has a very light framework for accessing disk and network.  That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have clustered database (for example, 1 master server and few read only replicas) pooling will help. 
Also you need to account the connection time needed to establish connection to database.
If you use pooling, you alwayes have few already established connection ready to perform requests

Comment: ok seems like a pool of at least 2 db connections is superior most of the time to just one